# Converting .gitlab-ci.yml file syntax into Jenkins.yaml

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I used gitlab mostly but I have requirement to run the GitLab CICD pipeline into Jenkins CICD Tool.
Considering I am newbie to Jenkins but experienced in Gitlab.

Pls let me know the conversion of my current `.gitlab-ci.yml` into jenkins.yaml file.

Current `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
before_script:
    - apt-get update -qq
    - apt-get install -qq git zip
test:                              
  environment: test
  script:
    - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY
    - apt-get update -qq
    - apt-get install -qq git zip
    - zip -r xyz.zip $CI_PROJECT_DIR 
    # - ssh -i $SSH_KEY -o stricthostkeychecking=no hello@<hostname> "pwd ; rm -rf xyz xyz.zip"
    - scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -i $SSH_KEY xyz.zip hello@<hostname>:/home/<linux_user>/
    - ssh -i $SSH_KEY -o stricthostkeychecking=no hello@<hostname> "pwd;rm -rf xyz; unzip xyz.zip -d xyz; chmod 700 -R xyz; rm -rf xyz.zip"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - xyz.zip
  only:
    changes:
      - abc/**/*
    refs:
        - test
```

Converted Jenkins Pipeline syntax:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    TEST = "test"
  }
  stages {
    stage("Test") {
      steps {
        sh "apt-get update -qq"
        sh "apt-get install -qq git zip"
        sh "chmod 400 ${SSH_KEY}"
        sh "apt-get update -qq"
        sh "apt-get install -qq git zip"
        sh "zip -r xyz.zip ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
        sh "scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -i ${SSH_KEY} xyz.zip hello@<hostname>:/home/<linux_user>/"
        sh "ssh -i ${SSH_KEY} -o stricthostkeychecking=no hello@<hostname> 'pwd;rm -rf xyz; unzip xyz.zip -d xyz; chmod 700 -R xyz; rm -rf xyz.zip'"
      }
      post {
        always {
          archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'xyz.zip', onlyIfSuccessful: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }
  triggers {
    changeset {
      pathFilters("abc/**/*")
    }
    branch 'test'
  }
}
```

Pls check and validate jenkins syntax (currently no access to jenkins instance) and will Jenkins above pipeline work in same way as it was working in gitlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't too difficult. All the `sh` commands you run can be run with Jenkins by enclosing them with `sh`. For example:

```
sh "chmod 400 $SSH_KEY"
sh "apt-get update -qq"
```

or a multi-line sh:

```
sh '''
  chmod 400 $SSH_KEY
  apt-get update -qq
  apt-get install -qq git zip
  zip -r xyz.zip $CI_PROJECT_DIR 
  ...
'''
```

A major difference between Jenkins and GitLab is that Jenkins has a huge ecosystem of [plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io) do things in a quicker and more efficient way. So it's best to consider if any of them might be useful to you.

The hardest part is setting up the triggers. While GitLab has an easy automatic trigger, Jenkins isn't designed with GitLab in mind, meaning that you will have to use the [GitLab plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/) to make the pipeline trigger. Take a look at the [triggers section](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/#plugin-content-job-trigger-configuration) of the documentation.

Comment: thanks @M B, I edit my query and added jenkins cicd pipeline, can you pls review?

Comment: The syntax is fine. And its pretty easy to get a Jenkins instance up and running to verify the syntax, which is the best way to make sure there are no problems.